# Visual Studio 2015 - Change Light Bulb, Quick Action settings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've started using Visual Studio 2015 today and really like the *Light Bulb* or *Quick Action* setting. I want to change these settings though, how do I do that?

Specifically the rule `IDE0003` which is trying to remove `this` from local properties or members.

[image]

How do I configure this rule or remove it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> trying to remove this from local properties or members.

There is a setting under Text Editor | C# which controls whether `this` is used for member access: does this control that rule? (I don't have an install to hand to get the exact name.)

Answer (score 24):

As @Richard suggested here comes the full path:

**Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style** and check **Qualify member access with 'this'**