# visual studio 2015 disable quick action "remove this qualitfication"

Tags: visual-studio, this, visual-studio-2015, quickaction

how can i prevent visual studio 2015 quick actions to suggest me the "remove 'this' qualitfication" to simlify the name? i don't want to disable the quick actions itself, just this hint.
i cant find any settings in the options.
i've already tried a few settings.

this is the message i'm talking about:

[image]

hope you can help, its driving me crazy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 - Change Light Bulb, Quick Action settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563049/visual-studio-2015-change-light-bulb-quick-action-settings)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

just found the solution!
you have to check the following checkbox:
tools -> options -> text editor -> c# -> code style -> qualify member access with 'this'

[image]

Comment: I knew where that option was, but I uncheck it and nothing changes! Nice, Microsoft!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to cyptus answer, Visual Studio 2017, allows different actions to be taken when using `this` and other supported keywords.

[image]