# Is this really a simplification?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

So I have a pretty simple class with an `Id` field, and the `Id` can be set in the constructor.

Typically I will use `this` to clearly identify the class property as opposed to the method argument. To me this seems clearer.

IDE0003 wants me to remove the `this`, with the message 'Name can be simplified', is that correct?

This seems less clear to me, and also allows a casing error to easily result in `id = id`.

[image]

Comment: Well, I think you already said it all: Not every 'simplification' is also a 'clarification'..

Comment: i think they both compile into same thing. so you just simplify what you have written nothing else.

Comment: Hmm, these kind of questions only ever seem to be asked by programmers that use a black editor window background.  Yeah, that lightbulb is pretty visible.  Much easier to not be bothered by it when the background is light :)  Sure it is a "simplification", there's less code.  But it makes absolutely no difference at runtime and it sure doesn't help you use auto-completion.

Comment: @Hans I use dark themes for my editors and hereby execute my right to feel offended. ;)

Comment: Perhaps, @Hans meant it as a harmless jibe?

Comment: Yes, at Microsoft.  Heck of an oversight, wasn't it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `this` keyword almost always is unnecessary, see [When do you use the "this" keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword).

> allows a casing error to easily result in `id = id`

That will yield another warning on its own:

> Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?

Comment: C# is case sensitive. In this case it would indeed be a simplification to remove This.

Comment: @DieterB, if C# is case sensitive (as it is) then what would indeed be a simplification would be removing `this`, not `This` :p

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are there any articles from Microsoft that have some justification as to why rules like this were enabled by default? E.g., why didn't they just have the default ruleset accept anything, since VS 2013 didn't enforce or pay attention to any particular style?

Answer (score 36):

This other question has an answer that says you can configure the editor to remove the behavior. Personally I like "this"

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style and check Qualify member access with 'this'
```

[Visual Studio 2015 - Change Light Bulb, Quick Action settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563049/visual-studio-2015-change-light-bulb-quick-action-settings)

Comment: Using the keyword `this` explicitly reveals where the variable exists. If it's not prefixed with `this`, `base`, or the name of the class (for static methods), the variable's scope is local and as global as a method. This makes the intention and readability more clear than its omission.

Answer (score 6):

If you use [`General Naming Conventions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx) then the `this` keyword is redundant because the parameter should be `id` and the property should be `Id` based on [`Naming Guidelines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx). So it seems clear:

```
public int Id 
{ 
   get; 
   private set; 
}


public VSOMessage(int id)
{
    Id = id;
}
```

Please note that the guidelines itself don't say, to use or not use `this` keyword but because C# is **case sensitive**, it would be a simplification to remove `this` keyword but **when you don't use** *Naming Conventions* then you may naming the property `id` instead of`Id` so you should use `this` keyword in such cases.

Comment: The keyword [`this`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) is explicitly useful for this scenario: "To qualify members hidden by similar names". Besides, not every member variable is a property and some properties may have a backing variable (especially useful for immutable objects). Additionally using `this`, `base`, and class name for static methods improves readability and solidifies intention.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent the warning in code rather then updating Visual Studio settings, use the `SuppressMessage` data annotation, which will prevent the warning.

It looks something like this:

```
[SuppressMessage("Reason #Enter whatever you'd like", "ID, must match what intellsense is showing it looks something like this: IDE0001", Justification = "(optional, your own description")]
```

Here is an exact example for your "this" variable situation:

```cs
[SuppressMessage("IntelliSenseCorrection", "IDE0003", Justification = "Allowing usage of 'this' keyword to maintain consistency/readability of code.")]
```

Comment: Note that this must be applied to the function declaration, not the "offending" statement. Attempting to apply it to the statement raises "CS7014: Attributes are not valid in this context". This was the solution I was looking for, however. Thanks!