# What are the arguments against using 'this' inside a C# class?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm almost done reading John Skeet's book *C# In Depth, Third Edition*, and I'm surprised that he doesn't use `this.property` inside `class`es. But since it's John Skeet, I'm sure that means there is a good reason for it.

**Example (from pg. 466):**

```
class AsyncForm : Form
{
    Label label; 
    Button button;
    public AsyncForm ( )
    {
       label = new Label { Location = new Point(10, 20),
                            Text = "Length" };
       button = new Button { Location = new Point(10, 50),
                             Text = "Click" };
       button.Click += DisplayWebSiteLength;
       Autosize = true;
       Controls.Add(label);
       Controls.Add(button);
    }
    // ... 
}
```

No `this` on `Autosize` and `Controls`, eh? Shouldn't we use `this` in order to avoid ambiguity as to whether the variable refers to a member of the class or some variable that is global with respect to the class?

I'm wondering because I want to make sure all the code I write is Skeet-certified?

Comment: Well, that's just a syntactic sugar.

Comment: I think this could a good reference for you .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword

Comment: Code style is strictly opinion based question. You can check out existing off-topic discussions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword for more info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this really a simplification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186954/is-this-really-a-simplification)

Comment: @user2946329: That is one clever title.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If I'm asking "What are the arguments against ..." I'm asking for objective criteria of the language

Comment: The linked question list cases you are looking for - if you are looking to find other cases - read C# specification carefully and ask separate specific questions if you find more usages that you have concerns about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class and is
>   also used as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method.[From MSDN]

**AsyncForm** class is inheriting Form class. The two property which you are talking about is the property of Form class not the AysncForm class, that's why there is no **this** keyword used with these two property.

I will give one simple use case for **this**.

```
public class Person
{
   public string name;// this is global variable
   public Person(string name)
   {
     //now we have two variable with name 'name' and we have ambiguity. 
     //So when I will use this.name it will use the global variable.

     this.name = name; //will assign constructor name parameter to global name variable. 
    //If I will do name = name, it will use the local variable for assigning the value into 
     //local variable itself because local variable has high priority than global variable.
   }
}
```

For better readability of code I would suggest to always use '_' in global variable name like.

```
public string _name;
```

and inside constructor

```
_name = name;
```

All other use of this keyword please check this answer.
[When do you use the "this" keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword)