# What is the difference in implementaton of constructor by using keyword this.?

Tags: c#, constructor, reference

please could you explain me what is the difference between this two implementation of constructors:

```
 public User(string a, string b)

    {

        name = a;

        location = b;

    }
```

and this one:

```
  public User(string a, string b)

    {

        this.name = a;

        this.location = b;

    }
```

From the compiler point of view I don't see any difference. Please explain it.

Comment: There is no difference. However, if the parameter name happened to be the same as the field or property name being assigned, you would *have* to use `this.` to disambiguate the assignment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33187034/2946329

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of "this" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270774/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference,

`this` just references the class, its useful if the parameters you pass in have the same name as the fields in your class (to differentiate from them)

```
public class Employee
{
    private string alias;
    private string name;

    public Employee(string name, string alias)
    {
        // Use this to qualify the members of the class 
        // instead of the constructor parameters.
        this.name = name;
        this.alias = alias;
    }
}
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[this (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this)

> The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class and is
>   also used as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method

Comment: Is it good practice to use also 'this' to the different variable and constructor parameteres or if they are only the same?

Comment: @Heron i dont use `this` in that case, some people like it as it stands out, it depends how you like to write your code, someone people like private field names to start with underscore . ie `_field` some dont, if it helps you, then just be consistent, personally, i use underscore for field names , they stick out