# How can I get the "Light bulb" refactoring tool in visual studio to use explicit types and not var?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, refactoring

When I use the light bulb refactor built into Visual Studio to generate a local variable it always uses the `var` syntax:

[image]
[image]

I (personally) don't like `var` and would prefer to  it to use an explicit type (in this instance `double`). so it should create the code:

```
double v = CalculateDownTime(lineid, start, end);
```

How can I alter the Visual Studio settings so that it will do this? Is it possible?

Please don't discuss the pros and cons of `var` vs explicit types. And no I don't want to use Resharper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found it, this [related question helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563049/visual-studio-2015-change-light-bulb-quick-action-settings?rq=1)

Untick the `Use var when generating locals` under:

[image]